# Do linux also have nonpage memory?

Tags: linux, drivers, memory

In Windows, we can find non-page memory and it was used for kernel and driver. ( in my understanding ).

1. Does Linux also have non-page memory?
2. In my understanding, for every byte of memory, it must in an allocated page then it can be used in kernel/userspace, why there is non-page memory working in Windows? ( or also for Linux )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Paged” in the Windows world has [a specific meaning](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-pools): paged memory is memory that can be paged to disk (swapped out, in Linux terms), non-paged memory is memory that can’t.

1. Yes, Linux also has non-paged memory, following this terminology; the kernel can’t be swapped out, and user processes can also allocate memory which is “locked” in physical memory and can’t be wapped out.
2. See above; here paging isn’t about mapping memory pages. Both Windows and Linux map memory using pages, and memory can’t be accessed (even by the kernel) if it isn’t mapped in a page.

Comment: The nonpage memory is zone-dma, zone-dma32 ?

Comment: No; the unswappable memory reserved by the kernel is removed from the available memory (so `MemTotal` in `/proc/meminfo` is reduced by that amount), and other unswappable memory is counted in `Unevictable` in `/proc/meminfo`. Zones are used to allocate memory in certain physical areas.